# How to get data generated by script on HTML page using VBA?

Tags: javascript, html, vba, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to parse a [Website](http://app.startupeuropeclub.eu/companies/pld_space) using VBA. My goal is to extract the data of the company (The name, website, location, investors, date of investment, amount of investment etc.) and to store it in an excel sheet. My function to extract the HTML source is the following (it works, at least on my computer...). I use late binding to have a better portability.

```
Private Sub getHTMLFromURL()

    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim implTmp As Object

    Set objHTTP = VBA.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    on error GoTo endProgram

    With objHTTP
        .Open "GET", URLStr, False
        .send

        If .READYSTATE = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
            html.Open
            html.write .responseText
            html.Close
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .READYSTATE & _
            vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
            GoTo endProgram
        End If

    End With

endProgram:
    Set html = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Error in getHTMLFromURL " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    End If

End Sub
```

My problem is that the HTML is one huge SCRIPT tag in which the data are hidden. For example, I guess the Headquarter location of the company is in this line of code:

```
{"key":"hqLocations","name":"Location","sortable":false,"getText":"function getText(c) {\n    return getHQCity(c.hqLocations);\n  }"}
```

I humbly admit that I have absolutely no clue on how to get these data. I have searched a lot in multiple forums without finding a fitting answer. I tried to adapt [this method](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?36175-Html-Script-tag-parameters-retrieve-with-VBA) without success. Thus I have several questions linked to my issue:

- Is using MSXML2.XMLHTTP the best way to do so?
- Do I have to fish for each variable or is there a way to directly interpret the script to have an HTML with all the data (which would be much easier then)?
- Otherwise, how can I extract all the data (single data and arrays)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your provided description only brings obscurity about the output you wish to have. Please be precise and tell exactly what is your expected output. Btw, don't mention the class name or tag name: just tell about the data that are visible on that site.

Comment: I just edited my post, I hope it is clearer like that. I would like to get, more or less, all the information displayed on the page. Especially what is in the "general" frame and in the "funding rounds" frame.

Comment: As you have already noticed that using `XMLHTTP` request you will get json response. However, when you wanna parse the desired fields from that response you either need to apply `split` function on `.responsetext` or `vba-json parser`. The best way to go about is choosing `InternetExplorer` as an option. If you have no problem with that then I can try. Thanks.

Comment: I am very curious about how you do it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below script. When you run it, you should get the required data you have requested in your post:

```
Sub Fetch_Data()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object, hdata As Object
    Dim elem As Object, trow As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://app.startupeuropeclub.eu/companies/pld_space"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    ''the following line is let the scraper wait until the data is completely loaded
    Do: Set hdata = HTML.getElementsByClassName("field"): DoEvents: Loop Until hdata.Length > 1

    For Each post In hdata
        With post.getElementsByClassName("title")
            If .Length Then R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("description")
            If .Length Then Cells(R, 2) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
    Next post

    ''avoiding hardcoded delay and wait until the data is completely loaded
    Do: Set posts = HTML.querySelector(".card-content.with-padding table.simple-table"): DoEvents: Loop While posts Is Nothing

    For Each elem In posts.Rows
        For Each trow In elem.Cells
            C = C + 1: Cells(I + 10, C) = trow.innerText
        Next trow
        C = 0
        I = I + 1
    Next elem
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Wow, works perfectly, thanks a lot!! (I just changed `Dim IE As Object, HTML As Object` and `Set IE = VBA.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` to avoid importing the libraries.